# Avoid data binding between variables in Angular 2

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have a Class in Angular 2 and I need two variables with the same json value, but I will need to change one and I need to keep the another one as a backup of the first, like this:

```
export class Table {
  var1: any;
  var2: any;
}
```

Then, with a request to API:

```
ajax_request().then(data => {
  this.var1 = data;
  this.var2 = data;
});
```

If I make changes in this.var2, this.var1 will be changed too.

To avoid this, I'm making:

```
this.var1 = data;
this.var2 = JSON.stringify(this.var1);
this.var2 = JSON.parse(this.var2);
```

But I know It's not performance-friendly.
What is the appropriated way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to Angular2 data binding, this is just how JavaScript works.

You need to create a copy of the object to not have a change from one reference affect the other reference to the same object - like you already do in your current workaround.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344074/217408

Comment: Thanks. Big (my) mistake to say It's an issue from Angular 2.

Comment: Easy to make. It works the way you expect for primitive values like number, string, boolean, but for objects only the reference is copied, not the content.

Comment: Yes. After all, I found JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.var1)) is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.var1  = Object.assign({}, data);
```

Comment: Not functional.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.